# JS: Pushing a new object into nested array-objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node-red

I want to build a nested JS object, with an array, objects, arrays, etc, that will keep `homie` variables at different levels, closely resembling an easy storage structure to store and retrieve from the homie v3.0.1 [convention](https://homieiot.github.io/specification/). (I include some of my own structures into the JS objects & arrays, to improve readiblity & flexibility of the code, like grouping variables leading with an _ underscore, so its not the same as the homie convention.)

The structure of the nested array / objects to be stored (in Node-RED global context - in JS object format), which I call the `homie Shadow`, (roughly `deviceID > nodeID > propertyID > propAttribute`, where devices, nodes, properties are all arrays of nested objects), `are`:

```
[
  {"deviceID":
    {"_nodesArr":
        [
          {
            "nodeID":{
              "_propArr":[
                {"propertyID":{"_propertyAttributes":
                    {"$attribute: attributeValue}}}
  }  }    ]  }  }  ]
]
```

Below is an example dataset, which is stored in Node-RED in a global context variable called **homieShw** (short for homie Shadow):

```
[
  {"ESP70":
      {"_nodesArr":
        [
          {"Light": {
              "_propArr":
              [
                {"Switch":{
                          "val":1,
                          "_propAttributes":{"$settable":true}
  }  }    ]  }  }  ]
]
```

Now, heading to what I want to do, and my problem: The Javascript code, will receive messages from `mqtt`, to setup the above structure, but also update the variables, for instance, when the light of this ESP is switched off, the mqtt message looks as follows:

```
homie/ESP70/Light/Switch/1
```

Without needing to quote all the code I do, I have a specific problem - and that is to store into an array further down in the array hierarchy of the `homie Shadow` or variable `arrHomieShw` (retreived from the global context variable `homieShw`).

- To add an ESP device in the object's first array, the JS code, which tests if the deviceID is in the array already, and if not, adds a new element to the array **(this code works perfectly)**, from the incoming `mqtt message` above:

```
function checkDeviceArrCreated(deviceID, arrHomieShw){

    for (i=0; i < arrHomieShw.length; i++) {
        if(deviceID !== Object.keys(arrHomieShw[i])[0] ) {
            foundDeviceID = 0 } else { foundDeviceID = 1; break }
    }
    if(foundDeviceID === 0){  
        branch = {[deviceID]:{ "_deviceAttributes": {  "$homie": $homie  } }};
        arrHomieShw.push( branch );
    }
}
```

- The above function checks if the object exits, and if it does not, it pushes the new branch into arrHomieShw, this works perfectly.
- But now, I want to do same for the array at the next level of the hierarchy of `homieShw`. Thus, I want to write into the **node** array of objects, by checking if the nodeID exist for the deviceID, and if not, to push a new branch into it.
- The push command does not want to push into a hierarchy as explained above.  This is what I have tried, (amongst others). The function `checkNodesArrCreated()` is called, with for instance with this mqtt message : `homie/ESP70/Air/Temperature/23`, after the variable `arrIdxDevice = getDeviceIdx();` - see this function also below.
- In the function `checkNodesArrCreated()`, the branch variable - which is pushed into the nested array `arrHomieShw` creates a new object, and does not branch below the same deviceID it found. I also tried to use variations of arrHomieShw.deviceID.push( branch ), but this also does not work.

How should I go about this?

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
function checkNodesArrCreated(){
    if(deviceID == Object.keys(arrHomieShw[arrIdxDevice])[0] ) {
        theObj = Object.values(arrHomieShw[arrIdxDevice][deviceID])
        if(theObj._nodesArr === undefined){
            branch = { _nodesArr:
                          {[nodeID]:{"_nodeAttributes": {  [nodeAttribute]: val  } } }
                      };
            arrHomieShw.push( branch );
        }
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
function getDeviceIdx(){
    for (i=0; i < arrHomieShw.length; i++) {
        if(deviceID == Object.keys(arrHomieShw[i])[0] ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return arrIdxDevice;
}

function getNodeIdx(deviceID, nodeID, arrIdxDevice, arrHomieShw){
    for (j=0; j < arrHomieShw[arrIdxDevice][deviceID]._nodesArr.length; j++) {
        if(nodeID == arrHomieShw[arrIdxDevice][deviceID]._nodesArr[j]){
            return j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you could replace all those arrays with objects and make everything much easier. For example: ` "_propArr":{switch: {...}}` the way you don't have to go through useless array searches on objects with one unique key, you would just use: `propArr.switch`.

Comment: The thing is, the model needs to apply for multiple Devices (30 - 100), (like a server, or Raspberry Pi, or an ESP8266), each device could have multiple Nodes, (measure door open / closed, measure Air conditions), each node can have multiple Properties (Pressure, Temp, Humidity), and each of them multiple Attributes. It looks like using Arrays for Devices, Nodes, Proporties are the right way to go - I have tested the model with only objects already. How would one do it if I stick with Arrays?